# How to fix "Error: HTMLHint not found, ..., CodeMirror HTML linting cannot run." error in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to get HTML linting working for my CodeMirror instance. I'm able to get CSS and JS linting working fine but HTML linting is not working. I'm still getting the "`Error: HTMLHint not found, not defined on window, or not available through define/require, CodeMirror HTML linting cannot run.`" error in the console log for HTML. Where do I include the global "`HTMLHint`" variable?

I have already downloaded the required HTML linting file (*// Depends on htmlhint.js from http://htmlhint.com/js/htmlhint.js*) and linked it in the "`<head>`".

```
<head>
       <script src="plugin/HTMLHint-develop/dist/htmlhint.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            theme: "rubyblue",
            mode: "htmlmixed",
            scrollbarStyle: "simple",
            indentUnit: 4,
            lineNumbers: true,
            lineWrapping: true,
            foldGutter: true,
            lint: true
        });
</script>
```

I would expect that the linting would work based on the "`<script></script>`" tag. Obviously I must be missing something.

Comment: That doesnt look like a relative URL path, try adding `../` before the src string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the HTML Hint js file it says:

// Depends on htmlhint.js from http://htmlhint.com/js/htmlhint.js

Here is a working link in github.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/htmlhint/brackets-htmlhint/master/htmlhint/htmlhint.js

Simply include it in your page.